# Is this the right tense / verbal form?

Tags: tenses, conjugation

I'm wondering whether, in the following sentence, the verbal form is correct/idiomatic. It sounds right to my ear, but since I'm not a native speaker, I can't tell for sure.

> After **having been granted** access to a site, the user can authenticate against the web server through Basic Authentication.

I think this is continuous present perfect in the passive voice (unless I'm mistaken), and it coincides with the fact that now that the user *has been granted access*, they can authenticate.

Can someone explain further, and correct the sentence if need be?

Comment: That is just fine.

Comment: The sentence is correct. You can also read the sentence as 'As the user now has access to a site, he (the user) can authenticate against the web server through basic authentication.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Having been" is a case of *[the perfect participle](https://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/participleperfect.html)*.

> The perfect participle indicates completed action. You form the perfect participle by putting the present participle *having* in front of the past participle.
>
> For example:- *having done, having finished, having read, having spoken*

This would encompass your example, because "been" is the [past participle](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/been) of "*be*."

It is perfectly appropriate to use in your situation, since you are discussing a situation that is completed.  The user can authenticate against the web server **after** the granting of access is complete.